# Typo3 9 - routing - cHash in news list

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

I am using the following config.yaml for the standard news plugin:

```
NewsPlugin:
  type: Extbase
  limitToPages:
    - 3
    - 15
  extension: News
  plugin: Pi1
  routes:
    -
      routePath: '/l/{page}'
      _controller: 'News::list'
      _arguments:
        page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
    -
      routePath: '/tag/{tag_name}'
      _controller: 'News::list'
      _arguments:
        tag_name: overwriteDemand/tags
    -
      routePath: '/{news_title}'
      _controller: 'News::detail'
      _arguments:
        news_title: news
    -
      routePath: '/archiv/{year}/{month}'
      _controller: 'News::archive'
  defaultController: 'News::list'
  defaults:
    page: '0'
    news_title: ''
    tag_name: ''
    year: '2019'
    month: '01'
  aspects:
    news_title:
      type: PersistedAliasMapper
      tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
      routeFieldName: path_segment
```

Now it all works pretty well, the only problem is, when I use the pagination, there is always a cHash attached to my url. Like a link to page 2 results in

http://www.example.com/newspage/l/2?cHash=313213213213213a2f13asf321

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cHash will be added if the [requirements](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html#simple-enhancer) are too loose or if there are no requirements at all. It can also be avoided with a [StaticRangeMapper](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html#staticrangemapper).

I'm also struggling with setting up the routeEnhancers for news. You may have a look at [my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420293/good-practice-on-how-to-set-up-routeenhancers-for-list-and-detail-view-of-extne) for applying pagination without cHash.

Comment: thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed! it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ben I found a solution that worked:

```
NewsPlugin:
  type: Extbase
  extension: News
  plugin: Pi1
  routes:
    -
      routePath: '/l/{page}'
      _controller: 'News::list'
      _arguments:
        page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
    -
      routePath: '/tag/{tag_name}'
      _controller: 'News::list'
      _arguments:
        tag_name: overwriteDemand/tags
    -
      routePath: '/{news_title}'
      _controller: 'News::detail'
      _arguments:
        news_title: news
    -
      routePath: '/archiv/{year}/{month}'
      _controller: 'News::archive'
  defaultController: 'News::list'
  defaults:
    page: '0'
    news_title: ''
    tag_name: ''
    year: '2019'
    month: '01'
  aspects:
    news_title:
      type: PersistedAliasMapper
      tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
      routeFieldName: path_segment
    '@widget_0/currentPage':
      type: StaticRangeMapper
      start: '1'
      end: '1000'
```

Comment: I've just tried your new solution: the paginator link from /l/2 (page 2) to the first page has lots of get parameters like ?tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=list&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&cHash=123456789. Does it work in your environment?