# Speaking URLs in TYPO3 9.5

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I tried to use:

`Behavoir >> URL Alias - "team"`

and receive:

`http://remax-prestige.pl/typo3-95/index.php?id=team`

team is ok, but how I can receive the link without `index.php?id=`

Comment: Did you add a Site in the Site management with your domain and language settings? This is mandatory for building the URL.

Comment: Yes, now is OK. Many thanks

Comment: Is ok, but withou ending "/" - e.g. "..../team"

Comment: That's answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53144596/how-a-add-an-appending-to-typo3-v9-urls

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a site in the Site Management module. When having a domain and path prefix, TYPO3 can make nice URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add TrailingSlash Settings in your Site Management `config.yaml`

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: '/'
    suffix: '/'
    index: ''
    map:
      '/': 0
      'sitemap.xml': 1533906435
```

This works for me.